# Perl nested structures

Tags: perl

I have a question regarding complicated structures in Perl

```
my $data1 = [
  +{ id => 1, name => 'A' },
  +{ id => 2, name => 'B' },
  +{ id => 3, name => 'C' },
];

my $data3 = +{
   1 => +{ id => 1, name => 'A' },
   2 => +{ id => 2, name => 'B' },
   3 => +{ id => 3, name => 'C' },
};
```

How should I print "B"?
What kind of data structure is that?
And any nice reference on Perl nested structures (hash references, array references, etc.) that is eay to understand?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know Data::Dumper ?

Comment: yes but im trying to do it without using modules

Comment: i know that when its a $data1= [[1,'a']] we can dereference it and print it with a "print $data1->[1][1];" simple line but i have never seen these weird ones before

Comment: [tutorial on data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) might be a good start for complex data structures like you have here.

Comment: I'm not sure what those `+` are doing in there?!

Comment: `+` disambiguates in places where the braces could be taken to be a code block instead of an anonymous hash reference, but one rarely needs that.  I'm guessing the code contains them out of a misplaced desire to be clear and consistent with places where it could be ambiguous.

Comment: @aidan there is no need to have the + indeed

Comment: @rra yes i think it was put there to make it "clearer"

Comment: I didn't even know that was valid Perl!

Comment: Btw, I really dislike perldsc, its a crutch giving recipes for each situation. To really understand references I like to point people to [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut) which makes it nice and clear.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this :

```
print $data1->[1]->{name}; # ARRAY ref
print $data3->{2}->{name}; # HASH ref
```

This is *de-reference* from a perl ARRAY and HASH ref.

The `->` *de-reference* explicitly. It's only needed for the first "floor", ex :

```
print $data1->[1]{name};
print $data3->{2}{name};
```

Works too. The 2nd and more are optionals.

Like Chris Charley said, take a look to the [tutorial on data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

---

To help you understanding what your scalar ref looks like, use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) , ex :

```
print Dumper $data1;
print Dumper $data3;
```

Should output :

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'name' => 'A',
            'id' => 1
          },
          {
            'name' => 'B',
            'id' => 2
          },
          {
            'name' => 'C',
            'id' => 3
          }
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'name' => 'A',
                   'id' => 1
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'name' => 'C',
                   'id' => 3
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'name' => 'B',
                   'id' => 2
                 }
        };
```

---

For the `+{ }` syntax, [rra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178404/rra) gives a good response :

> disambiguates in places where the braces could be taken to be a code block instead of an anonymous hash reference, but one rarely needs that. I'm guessing the code contains them out of a misplaced desire to be clear and consistent with places where it could be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does print now and by the answer you gave I somehow got an idea of what kind of thingies these are

Comment: Note that you don't always have to be explicit about dereferencing. After the first `->`, using more of them to dereference is optional - `$data1->[1]{name}` is equivalent to `$data1->[1]->{name}`.

Comment: Btw, I really dislike perldsc, its a crutch giving recipes for each situation. To really understand references I like to point people to [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut) which makes it nice and clear.