# Mason - Passing a map of strings to a service call

Tags: perl, dictionary, mason

I am trying to pass a map of string to a service call that I am making from my .mi file.

I am trying the below but it gives me syntax error at ");".

```
  my $serviceResult = PI::employee::register::Service->saveAttributes(
          attributesMap => map { ('session-id' => $Session->getSessionId())}
      );
```

If I instead try

```
 my $serviceResult = PI::employee::register::Service->saveAttributes(
          attributesMap => map { 'session-id' => $Session->getSessionId()}
      );
```

It says not enough arguments for map. :(

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about Mason at all.  Instead, it appears to be about how to correctly use your `PI::employee::register::Service` class.  (Not to mention `map`.)  We're not going to know what its API is supposed to be.

Comment: It is about mason only .. PI is just referring to perl client that I am using to access a service.

Comment: I am getting a mason syntax error .. now does it make sense to you

Comment: You are reporting parse errors.  Because you are not producing valid Perl.  Mason is not your problem.

Comment: Look at perl hashes, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537157/perl-nested-structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl's `map` function, as documented in [`perldoc -f map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) takes a `BLOCK` (or `EXPR`) and a `LIST`.  You are not supplying a `LIST`, therefore your code does not compile.

You can get rid of the parse error by supplying a list:

`map { ('session-id' => $Session->getSessionId()) } (1)`

This is almost certainly not what you want, though.  You are using `map` in error.  You want a map from keys to values, which is not what the `map` function is for.

Instead of the call to `map`, it looks like you need a hashref like

`{ 'session-id' => $Session->getSessionId() }`

.

Comment: Function takes three parameters - String, String, Map<String, String>

Comment: So it is obvious that `attributesMap => map { 'session-id' => $Session->getSessionId()} (1)` cannot be correct.

Comment: So please suggest .. how shall I pass the map . :( .. all I want to do is pass a map with key "session-id" and value $Session->getSessionId()

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the new things I've learned about the API you are calling.